# An Internet browser Qt4 widget?

Tags: python, windows, qt4, pyqt4

I'm want to show in the GUI a small box (400x85) that shows in an HTML file over the web.
The `QtWebKit` class got his `QWebView` widget, but the whole `QtWebKit` class is VERY heavy, weights 16MB, and slows the init of the application in three seconds.

It's not really necessary to load the whole `QtWebKit` class just to show an HTML page.
It is possible to use IE's built in web engine? (Through an ActiveX Object or something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Internet Explorer via ActiveQT. There is a c++ example in "yourqtdir\4.8.0\examples\activeqt\webbrowser".

Comment: Thank you. Just for the record, this is the code that i used:
self.browser = QAxContainer.QAxWidget()
  self.browser.setControl("{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}")
  self.browser.dynamicCall('Navigate(const QString&)', QtCore.QString("http://www.google.com"))